# Overloading Java class constructors

Tags: java, class, overloading

I need to overload constructor of the BigInteger class to create an instance of VeryLong from `int` and `long`. Here is my code:

```
    private ArrayList<Long> A = new ArrayList<>();

    private VeryLong(int n) {
        while (n > 0) {
            A.add(long()(n % 10));
            n /= 10;
        }

        while (!A.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println(A.get(0));
            A.remove(0);
        }
    }

    private VeryLong(long n) {
        while (n > 0) {
            A.add(n % 10);
            n /= 10;
        }

        while (!A.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println(A.get(0));
            A.remove(0);
        }
    }
```

If I define A as `ArrayList` of `Long` there goes error in first constuctor. Similarly, it's error in `add()` method in second, if i define `A` as `Vector<Integer> A = new Vector<Integer>();`. How can I fix it?

Comment: You get the error with the code you've shown, or when you change your code to use `Vector`? Can we see the error? Where do `BigInteger` constructors come into this?

Comment: Why do you even need separate overloads for `int` and `long`? The `long` one would do the same as the `int` one. And why add to an `ArrayList` only to remove it all again?

Comment: You're using the ArrayList to store digits of the number in the range 0-9. You don't need it to be `ArrayList<Long>`, `ArrayList<Integer>` (or `ArrayList<Byte>`) is just fine for both constructors. You need to learn the proper casting syntax.

Comment: These are pretty strange constructors. They fill up a member variable (A) with digits and then empty it again.  That is, they 'construct' nothing useful.

Answer (score 1):

The error in the constructor is due to the wrong casting syntax:

It should be `A.add((long)(n % 10));`, not `A.add(long()(n % 10));`